# CheckBox in Telerik Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

**The Objective:**

Insert a CheckBox for each row of a Telerik Grid and when the user press submit recive all checkbox changes to the Controller.

I'm using C# ASP.net MVC3

**The Question:**

- I was looking on-line tutorials and Telerik help but they allways use javascript to send the ID of the selected Items, I'm not sure if it's possible to bind directly to the model and save checkbox changes automathically to avoid javascript.

**The code:**

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Article>()
.Name("ArticleGrid")
.DataKeys(keys =>
{
    keys.Add(article => article.Code);
})
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Description)
    columns.Bound(article => article.Selected).Width("35px")
            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='<#= Code #>' id='IsSelected<#= Code #>' />")
            .Title("")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
})
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select( "_SelectArticlesAjax", Controllers.Valoration})
)
)
```

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue.